# Calculating daily balance stock using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables sales and procurement. Sales tables contains the daily sales data and procurement contains the stock purchased. Now What I want to do is to create a measure, or a column, or a calculated table (whichever works best) to calculate balance stock or stock in hand for each day. But I don't know how I can do it in Power BI I am attaching my dataset below:

Procurement Table :
[image]

Sales Table :

[image]

Comment: pleasre share your input/output preferrably not images.

Comment: How can I upload an excel file with tables in it?

Comment: No need to upload it just share it as a text in the post

Comment: This is the Procurement Table

Category ID Client ID Date Price / Kg (PKR) Price / MT (PKR) Price / Cyl. (PKR) Qty Procured (Kg) Qty. Procured (MT) Value (PKR) Bowswer #
2 5 1/2/2024 0:00 239.1308719 239130.8719 2821.744288 26253 26.253 6277902.779 11
1 2 1/3/2024 0:00 238.1902753 238190.2753 2810.645248 29799 29.799 7097832.012 12
1 3 1/6/2024 0:00 241.7956409 241795.6409 2853.188563 25326 25.326 6123716.402 13
2 3 1/16/2024 0:00 243.4768227 243476.8227 2873.026508 23544 23.544 5732418.315 15
2 3 1/16/2024 0:00 245.569072 245569.072 2897.71505 26676 26.676 6550800.565 14